# Trekking poles with many attachments?

Tags: trekking-poles

Can anyone point to any commercial or DIY trekking poles whose end-piece can be swapped -- i.e. regular pole point, sharp spear, raft paddle, camera screw, etc?

Comment: In thinking about this, it would seem that it could be better to fit items like camera screws to the other end, keeping the pole point.

Answer (score 2):

I would wager that such a thing does not exist. Of the attachments you mention, only one (sharp spear) seems practical. Issues with the others:

- Camera mount: as rory-alsop mentions, it would make sense for the handle to have a camera mount, so you can stick the point into the snow / ground. [This blogger](http://www.briangreen.net/2011/07/trekking-pole-camera-mounts.html) has a few options (among which is a tip-mount).
- Raft Paddle: the torque forces on a raft paddle are no match for a trekking pole. Even if you rigged something flat to the end, you'll bend your pole in no time. For casual paddling, you would be better off with a dead branch.

What else would you want to attach? Brainstorming, I came up with these (and alternatives):

- *Tent pole extender:* Some tents rely on trekking poles as their support, and as such include a sheath that extends the length.
- *Saw blade (for those hard to reach branches you want to burn):* Never cut branches from a standing tree. If you can't find dead and downed, you shouldn't have a fire.
- *Pack hanger*: Now this is something I have employed in rodent-infested areas - hanging your food bag from a trekking pole. Though in my experience, three poles wrapped together with their wrist straps does the trick - no attachment necessary (though a third pole is...)
- *Komodo Dragon Deterrent:* A forked stick is the [preferred defense against Komodo dragons](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1025244/Pictured-Mailman-confronts-Komodo-dragon-island-British-divers-struggled-survive.html), but although a modified trekking pole might work, you are probably better off letting your local guide carry a stick he is familiar with instead of your trekking pole (and running away while he uses it).
- Dental Mirror for a Bowhead Whale: You could use a mirror attachment to inspect the rear baleen of a [Bowhead Whale](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/records-2000/largest-mouth/)... other options... ummm...

Comment: Heh- dental mirror :-)